# Need a font with unambiguous letters for commonly confused characters

Tags: website-design, html, css, font

**Must-have**

A few stipulations for an unambiguous font:
 - It must be easily legible.
 - It must have a slashed zero (so as to distinguish it from
   capital O). 
 - It must sufficiently differentiate between the
   characters 1, l, |, and I.

**Why?** 
Because when people are writing code, or checking data and documents, they need to be able to distinguish easily between these characters.

**Nice-to-have**

Aesthetically pleasing

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on programmers.SE :-) Anyway, I too use Consolas.

Comment: How does this relate to User Experience? Are you designing an application that has programmers as end users? Do you expect the end users to be incapable of selecting a font that suits them, then?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming

Comment: Putting this on hold. It was probably closed off on StackOverflow because it's not a question with a correct answer. Also, as @DannyVarod points out it already has a closed duplicate on StackOverflow, and with 100+ answers it demonstrates why such questions don't really work in this format, but should also give you plenty of useful suggestions.

Comment: "If you throw a list of fonts at me" = likely why it's been closed everywhere you post it.

Comment: Useful comparisons: (a) [Samples of monospaced typefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces). (b) [Font Survey: 42 of the Best Monospaced Programming Fonts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming).

Comment: The Google Font [Source Code Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro) does a pretty code job for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Monospaced fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) can provide what you're looking for, a good example of which is [Consolas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolas).

Consolas is the standard font on Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, and Eclipse Indigo (the standard font on previous versions of both these tools being Courier New 10).

[image: Consolas Preview]

Consolas has been described ([here](http://neosmart.net/blog/2006/a-comprehensive-look-at-the-new-microsoft-fonts/)) as "...a sans-serif font with the same rounded appeal [as Lucida Console], but nevertheless retains the traditional "code" feel, with monospaced characters and a "boxy" look."

It holds [all the characteristics of a programming font](http://www.deadprogrammer.com/the-programmers-font); namely being sans-serif, fixed-width, slashed zero, and sufficient differentiation between the characters 1, l, |, and I.

[image: Consolas -- differentiation between similar characters]

Consolas is clear, concise, and (for the same font-size) takes up less room than Courier New.

Its only short-coming, however, is that it was built specifically for [ClearType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClearType), and is a commercial font. It ships with all major new Microsoft releases though, and is therefore most suited for programming on newer Windows machines (you can get it for Mac if you install Microsoft Office). As an alternative to Consolas on Mac or Linux, you could try [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_%28typeface%29), [Ubuntu Mono](http://font.ubuntu.com/), [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) or [Anonymous Pro](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/anonymous-pro).

If you'd like more options, check these articles:

[Hivelogic - Top 10 Programming Fonts](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts)

[Slant - What are the best programming fonts](http://www.slant.co/topics/67/~what-are-the-best-programming-fonts)

**UPDATE:**

Here's a graphical comparison of Consolas against the other fonts mentioned in this answer:

[image: Monospaced Typefaces comparison]

For a full list of the comparison, see [Samples of monospaced typefaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces) and some more here - [42 of the Best Monospaced Programming Fonts](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30040/Font-Survey-of-the-Best-Monospaced-Programming), courtesy of [comment from @Basil Bourque](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46142/need-a-font-with-unambiguous-letters-for-commonly-confused-characters/46144#comment100619_46142).

Comment: I do use DejaVu Sans Mono on Windows. Why not?

Comment: There is also a CSS enhancement that tweaks fonts that don't distinguish zero from O very effectively:

http://thenewcode.com/656/Generate-Distinct-Zeros-On-Web-Pages-With-OpenType

Comment: @YvonneAburrow: Interesting, thanks! That would be Plan B if one is keen on using a font that doesn't do it natively. Browser-specific issues might arise though.

Comment: Here is a fun bit of valid javascript valid that returns true... `Il1I=007 ; (0O07|0O10) === (0o10|Il1I)`. Ill be using a serif font like Dejavu serif, takes less space and gets the job done.

Comment: @RayFoss an elaborate way to demonstrate that bitwise OR is commutative, but it is also entertaining and it demonstrates the point that readability can be important and fonts contribute to that.

Answer (score 0):

I like your opening gambit! :)

For me I like courier new  in Sublime; but that doesn't answer your question. It also doesn't help that the default Windows font viewer uses the string 1-9 to display.

SNag's answer has everything down to a tee - especially when it comes to i, l and 1.

For a list of zero slash fonts look [here](http://www.k8zt.com/zero.html#fonts)

Knock yourself out.